# TypeError : Circle() takes no arguments

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting the error `TypeError : Circle() takes no arguments` when trying to run the code above. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
class Circle:  
    is_shape = True
    radius,color=0,""

def __init__(self, color, radius):
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius

def display(self):
    print("radius:",self.radius)
    print("color:",self.color)

first_circle = Circle("red",2)
first_circle.display()
```

Comment: Fix your indentation

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have an `indentation` problem in your code. Your functions aren't defined under classes, that's why it shows your class **Circle()** takes no argument.

To correct this put your functions inside a class :

```
class Circle:
    is_shape = True
    radius, color = 0, ""

    def __init__(self, color, radius):
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius

    def display(self):
        print("radius:", self.radius)
        print("color:", self.color)


first_circle = Circle("red", 2)
first_circle.display()
```